# Changing public IP

Tags: router, internet, ip, modem, isp

I am new on this site and if this question is off topic I deeply apologize.

I am trying to change my public IP address which does not seem to change when I reset the router or the change the MAC address of the router. My router does not have a modem because I have free internet that is provided free of charge by my apartment management. Most videos/ posts I have seen advise to reset the router and modem after cloning MAC address to a new device which is supposed to change the public IP. It does not happen in my case and I am assuming because I have no way to reset the modem.

In my router settings, it does mention that the IP is dynamic if that's relevant at all for the public IP.

Any help is appreciated and if this is off topic I will gladly take it down. Thanks!!

Comment: free or pay VPN are your choices

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Is it the only choice? I did try paid VPNs but it does not do the job for me for some work that I am doing

Comment: That is their purpose.

Comment: Sure, I get it. But I am also wondering if turning off the router doesn't work for me because I don't have access to the modem.

Comment: The ISP provides a public IP, and I suppose that public IP goes to the Modem. And that modem is not your modem.   Without stating what work you are doing, but giving an example of equivalent work that'd have the issue.  Why does a VPN not do the job?

Comment: @Heisenberg of course turning the router won't change things, as the modem has the IP so everybody in the entire block of flats has the same public IP. (at least I suppose that's how it works!)

Comment: @barlop mostly gaming related and I get ddosed or there is lag sometimes which I cannot afford. I just thought if I can change the IP of my home connection might be a better option. However, if the entire block has a shared IP, and there is no way I can switch off the modem (I don't even know where in the building it is), I think it's impossible to change the public IP.

Comment: that would make latency worse to use a VPN

Comment: I've actually found that many types of traffic run faster over VPN. there are many factors to establishing end-2-end latency, so provided you aren't struggling to get CPU/RAM for the crypto operations, it may actually be faster for an actual real world connection if the VPN endpoint comes out at a place with better bandwidth to the target server.

Comment: Changing your IP address won't make the lag go away. You should always ask a question describing your actual problem in as much detail as you can and avoid asking about how to implement what you think will solve the problem. You aren't giving us all the information we need to help you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for the comment. The main concern ( or curiosity) I have is why resetting the router never worked for me but it works for most people from what I have gathered online. But according to what I hear I think it's impossible without having any access to a modem

Comment: @Heisenberg It may even be the complex's router that the public IP address is assigned to with everyone in your complex sharing the same public IP. If you don't have your own Internet connection, you likely don't have your own public IP. Thus there is nothing for you to change.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks again. I am also wondering if there are any privacy concerns when other people I don't know use the same IP as I do. I am pretty sure that I am protected through my wifi password but I am skeptical.

Comment: There was a time when most of an entire country shared a single public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few concepts to consider here.

First note that if you don't have access to the device directly connected to the ISP network, you have absolutely no means to change your public IP address.

If you do have some degree of access, note that IP addresses are leased by the DHCP server to a device for a period of time. that lease is monitored on the DHCP server by the device MAC address, so if a device requests an address while its lease is still valid, the server will just serve them back the same address they already had. That means that rebooting your router in the middle of your lease duration will have no effect, but it does mean that if you have the means to change the MAC address of the router's WAN interface, that the server would forget your lease, and because the address in question is leased to another device, it will assign you a new one. this is probably the most surefire way to do it.

Alternately, turning off your device and leaving it off until your lease has expired may provide you a new IP (or it may not, depending on the number of clients in the address pool and the degree of churn), but this only provides the possibility of a real change.

Note that using a commercial VPN service is the most reliable way to ensure that your public endpoint is changing regularly, and will appear different to the servers you contact. if you don;t have access to the demarc device, it is the only real option you have (or a proxy, or TOR, I suppose, though those are both more limited and prone to issues than a VPN).

Finally note, that from a legal compliance/non-compliance perspective, if you ISP is asked and chooses to respond to a request for information about an IP on a date, or implement management on an endpoint on their network, they will have absolutely no difficulty telling which account had it at any given minute.

Comment: i've no the OP, but i've had the same public IP for almost a decade, I called my ISP to ask them to change it, they said sure, and I have had that IP they gave me for almost a decade. So what would that say re lease time? And how would one check the length of the lease?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Without knowing what the lease period is I just don't know for how long I need have the devices switched off.

Comment: the mechanism for determining lease will vary from device to device, if it is available at all. as for @barlop's IP, there is no reason that an ISP can't make persistent DHCP reservations for each subscriber, and update it as the modem device is replaced, or they may leverage service codes on the demarc to integrate with their DHCP systems. my comments are about typical/common norms in north America. but they will vary from ISP to ISP. Personally mine changes every couple of months.

Comment: @FrankThomas when you say "from device to device" do you mean the modem/ router or the computer?

Comment: @FrankThomas you write "and update it as the modem device is replaced"  <-- mine has  stayed static despite replacing modem.  Let's say I want to check from my computer? or from ddwrt firmware on router? how do you see the length of the lease?

Comment: @barlop, it is likely that your ISP is using technology other than leases if you have had it that long. the dhcp is probably integrated with their service entitlement and billing platform, and dynamically generating reservations. if you have a modem (not a router./modem combo), you could connect a windows system directly to the modem and run `ipconfig /all` from it. if the ISP supplies a router however, you will have to access it and look through logs or any other information it provides. there is not one answer for where to look on all devices.

Comment: @Heisenberg, I mean between makes and models of cable-modems. I just mean that there isn't one set of instructions that will work for every ISP device. Note that if they gave you a modem, you could just connect windows to it, since the ipconfig /all command will show details about the dhcp lease. if you are assigned an ISP router though, you will have to hope that the configuration screens display information about the lease. it may not.

Comment: @FrankThomas no they did not provide a modem or a router. All I had to do was get a router and there is a LAN port on my apartment wall. I connected my router to that port 
 and got internet.

Comment: then as stated, you;ll need to use another technology to misdirect your traffic, like a VPN or TOR or plain old proxy's. that's just all you can do.

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks. Are shared public IPs static usually to your knowledge ?

Comment: there's no good way to tell. you can implement NAT using a static or dynamic IP address on the WAN-side, and there isn't even a guarantee that there is only one NAT between you and your public IP. it depends entirely on the implementation. sorry.